# Can't create files on desktop in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, filesystem, files, rm

I accidentally created a desktop shortcut in my home directory.
To remove it, I did

```
sudo rm -rf Desktop
```

Now I can't create files and folders on my desktop.

Answer (score 2):

If you were in your home folder, then you deleted your entire `Desktop` folder...

Re-creating it with these should work:

```
cd ~
mkdir Desktop
```

And try not to use `rm -rf` without being absolutely sure what will be deleted next time. **Especially** with `sudo`.